# communicattion between process and subprocess

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing

I have writtern small multiprocess program and was expecting that order will
following way.

```
hello number
ls -l <output>
```

But It did not work. So I believe parent process is not aware of child process.
How main process can wait to finish child process. or I am missing very basic 
concept of multiprocessing

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import multiprocessing
import subprocess

def run_command():
    pipe = subprocess.Popen("ls -l", stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                    stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                                    shell=True)
    out, err = pipe.communicate()
    pipe.wait()
    print out, err

def msg(number):
    print "hello %s" %(number)
    run_command()

def main():
    print "yes"
    procs = []
    for i in range(0, 100, 1):
        process = multiprocessing.Process(target=msg, args=(i,))
        procs.append(process)
    for proc in procs:
        proc.start()
    for proc in procs:
        proc.join()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

Expected code:
hello 0
total 4
-rw-rw-r-- 1 goswamia <#> 682 Apr  6 02:51 check_process.py

hello 1
total 4
-rw-rw-r-- 1 goswamia <#> 682 Apr  6 02:51 check_process.py

etc
```

Getting output:
python check_process.py

```
yes
hello 0
hello 1
hello 2
hello 3
hello 4
total 4
-rw-rw-r-- 1 goswamia <#> 682 Apr  6 02:51 check_process.py

total 4
-rw-rw-r-- 1 goswamia <#> 682 Apr  6 02:51 check_process.py

total 4
-rw-rw-r-- 1 goswamia <#> 682 Apr  6 02:51 check_process.py

total 4
-rw-rw-r-- 1 goswamia <#> 682 Apr  6 02:51 check_process.py

total 4
-rw-rw-r-- 1 goswamia <#> 682 Apr  6 02:51 check_process.py
```

Comment: Instead of first starting every process, *and then* waiting for every process to finish, you'd have to wait for each process to finish *before* starting the next process. Simply remove the second `for proc in procs:`.

Comment: But then the whole concept of multiprocessing seems kind of pointless.

Comment: how can i handle such scenario if process create child process I want let child process finish and do parallel stuff

Comment: Parallel stuff is done between `start` and `join`.

Comment: yes than process invoke another function. i want to wait to finish such function

Comment: Please edit your post so that it contains a specific question with a minimal and complete example. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: this is complete example with working code. what is missing here?

Comment: You say that it "did not work" - *how* did it not work? You should describe what you expected to happen and what happend instead. Then in the comments you are talking about another function that is invoked by the subprocess. I don't understand how this relates to the code in the post. You should make that more clear.

Comment: update script output and desired ouput

Answer (score 0):

I am able to get out but not able to understand following line. really what it is doing if I comment the output does not come  in proper order

**psutil.Process(proc.pid).children() (Not able to understand this)**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import multiprocessing
import subprocess
import psutil

def run_command():
    pipe = subprocess.Popen("ls", stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                    stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                                    shell=True)
    out, err = pipe.communicate()
    print out, err

def msg(number):
    print "hello %s" %(number)
    run_command()

def main():
    print "yes"
    procs = []
    print multiprocessing.cpu_count()
    for i in range(0, 5, 1):
        process = multiprocessing.Process(target=msg, args=(i,))
        procs.append(process)
    for proc in procs:
        proc.start()
        psutil.Process(proc.pid).children()
    for proc in procs:
        proc.join()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score -1):

seems there is miss use of pipe.wait()

> edited: miss placed of pipe.wait() you should place your pipe.wait()
>   just like this edited code

here is your edited code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import multiprocessing
import subprocess


def msg(number):
    # this command for sub process
    pipe = subprocess.Popen("ls -l", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)

    # this command that runing in main process
    out, err = pipe.communicate()
    print "hello %s" %(number)
    print out, err

    # this make sub prosses waits for the command in main process to finish
    pipe.wait()

def main():
    print "yes"
    procs = []
    for i in range(0, 5, 1):
        process = multiprocessing.Process(target=msg, args=(i,))
        procs.append(process)
    for proc in procs:
        proc.start()
    for proc in procs:
        proc.join()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

that order will following what supose

```
hello number
ls -l <output>
```

other people already explained this [Using subprocess module to work in parallel (Multi-process)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31429849/using-subprocess-module-to-work-in-parallel-multi-process)

your first code executed in separate process and the output unordered because background process and foreground process are separate process too.

Comment: I have used pipe.wait() into my code I can not combine both function as into my process which is invoking another tool and does other stuff. will it possible to handle such case

Comment: is possible, you can run multiprocess and sub-process inside main process while sub-process is waiting its parent(main process). you can read more detailed information in python documentation here https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/multiprocessing.html